# Excel Formula For Fixed amount sliding scale amount

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to calculate the total amount of monthly fees based on the requirement price schedule below.

Price Schedule* – Monthly Fees per End User

```
1-100 end users:        $29 each
101 - 250 end users:        $27 each
251 - 500 end users:        $25 each
501 - 750 end users:        $23 each
750 - 1000 end users:   $21 each
1001 - 1500 end users:  $19 each
1501 - 2000 end users:  $15 each
2001 - 2500 end users:  $11 each
2501 - 5000 end users:  $9 each
5001+ end users:        $7 each
```

*The prices apply to each customer in their respective tier. For clarity, the fee for the first 100 end users remains at $29 regardless of the total number of end users. The fee for the 101st to 250th end user is $27, and so on.

The input would be the number of end-users and the output would be the total monthly fees

An example would be 150 end users and the output would be:

```
(100*29) + (49*27)
= 4,223
```

It is easy enough to manually calculate but really need a formula that is smart enough to calculate given just the number of end users

Comment: No offense, but that's a unique cost structure. So if the number of users is 300, the output is (100*29) + (150*27) + (50*25)???

Comment: No if it is 300 it would be (100*29)+(150*27)+(50*25) = 8200

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was this formula. Not sure if this is the best way but seems to work

```
=(MIN(B1,100)*29)+
MAX(0,(MIN(250-100,(B1-100))*27))+
MAX(0,(MIN(500-250,(B1-250))*25))+
MAX(0,(MIN(750-500,(B1-500))*23))+
MAX(0,(MIN(1000-750,(B1-750))*21))+
MAX(0,(MIN(1500-1000,(B1-1000))*19))+
MAX(0,(MIN(2000-1500,(B1-1500))*15))+
MAX(0,(MIN(2500-2000,(B1-2000))*11))+
MAX(0,(MIN(5000-2500,(B1-2500))*9))+
MAX(0,(B1-5000)*7)
```

Answer (score 1):

This sort of issue is usually best served by a lookup table and the `VLOOKUP` function.

It allows for easier maintenance if things might change in the future.

For example, set up your monthlyTable like this:

[image]

The first and third columns are entered manually.
The `Base` column is computed with the formula:

```
H2: 0
H3: =(G3-G2)*I2+H2
```

Then you can use the formula:

```
B2: =VLOOKUP(A2,monthlyFees,2)+(A2-VLOOKUP(A2,monthlyFees,1))*VLOOKUP(A2,monthlyFees,3)
```

[image]